# Goland remote development setup

Tags: go, goland

Im developing my first go project and i need to develop it on a remote linux server. Its something small and this is why i need something really simple, but 3rd day now im trying to setup my goland with no success. Starting to wonder if i need it at all here.

I already setup my SSH terminal and my SFTP. The problem is that im not sure how to write my code locally, build it locally and upload to the server or build it on the server. This is what i tried:

1. Tried to develop with remote file manager and remote terminal, just using goland as editor. The problem here is that if goland meets some missing package, it will give me errors, maybe here i can somehow ignore this?
2. Tried to write it locally, sync with remote on every save and compile it from the terminal, but this will create an issie with missing packages, but in general it works.
3. Tried to write it locally, compile it remotely from the Run options. The problem here is that i want to write my install.go file locally and upload it to /root/project/install as compiled file, but its creating some temporary files, tried even to overwrite my -o file from the "Go tool arguments", but it just adds the path to the existent one.
4. Tried to write it locally and compile it locally and then upload it to the server, but cant find the way for such thing at all.
5. Maybe dlv, but it looks like a simple issue, hope i wont have to install additional software on the server because of this.

Is some of those options valid or im missing another options? I hope you understood what i really want.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> but 3rd day now im trying to setup my goland with no success. Starting to wonder if i need it at all here

You don't need it.

> 4. Tried to write it locally and compile it locally and then upload it to the server, but cant find the way for such thing at all.

This is what you want.  The only thing you need to install on your server is the executable from `go build`, built for the server's architecture, which you can copy over SFTP.

When you want to run your program *locally*, you will use `go build` to produce an executable that you can run.

When you build for the *remote* server, you will want to set `GOOS` and `GOARCH` to the values appropriate for your server:

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o my-project.linux-amd64
```

If your server is ARM, substitute `arm64` for `amd64`.

Then copy `my-project.linux-amd64` to the server and it will be able to successfully run there.

> Im developing my first go project

Then make sure to understand this point:  *go executables don't need go libraries at runtime*.

This is a big selling point for Go, and is different from an interpreted language like Python, Javascript, Ruby, and also different from languages that run in a software virtual machine like JVM (Java) or BEAM (Erlang) baed VMs.

As a newcomer to go, please make sure to [read the tutorial](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started).

Save yourself a lot of hassle and [Write tests right away](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/add-a-test) as you develop your first project.   These should be your primary way of demonstrating functionality as you work on your project.